# How to trigger onChange on <input type='file' /> by another Button click in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<div style={{display: 'grid'}}>
    <button id='plus' onClick={???}>+</button>
    <input id='selectImage' type="file" onChange={fileSelectHandler} />
</div>
```

Here, I want to trigger the onChange function of input, by clicking the button. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can hide the original file input, and make it click by javascript on click of the button.

```
upload() {
  document.getElementById("selectImage").click()
}

<div style={{display: 'grid'}}>
  <button id='plus' onClick={this.upload}>+</button>
  <input id='selectImage' hidden type="file" onChange={fileSelectHandler} />
</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 15):

Create a ref:

```
//inside the constructor:
fileRef = React.createRef()
// in your input element
<input id='selectImage' type="file" onChange={fileSelectHandler} ref={this.fileRef} />
```

Now,

```
<button id='plus' onClick={this.triggerClick}>+</button>

triggerClick() {
  this.fileRef.current.click()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me. It will hide the ugly file input component, and allow you to trigger its click function when the button is clicked instead.

```
import React from 'react'

import {
    Button,
    Input,
    Label
} from 'reactstrap'

class UploadButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.fileInput = React.createRef() // ref to fileInput

    }

    // when called, triggers fileInput click function
    triggerInputFile = () => {
        if (this.fileInput.current != undefined && this.fileInput.current.click != undefined)
            this.fileInput.current.click()
    }

    // handle file upload 
    handleFileUpload = () => {
        // handle click
    }

    render() {
        var color = 'primary'
        return (
            <div className='content'>
                <Button
                    color={color}
                    onClick={() => this.triggerInputFile()}
                >
                    Upload

                </Button>

                <input
                    ref={this.fileInput}
                    type='file'
                    onClick={() => this.handleFileUpload()}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
            </div>

        )
    }
}


const styles = {
    input: {
        opacity: '0%', // dont want to see it
        position: 'absolute' // does not mess with other elements 
    }
}

export default UploadButton
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <div
                      class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 "
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.upload.click();
                      }}
                    >
                      <h4 align="center">
                        <label class="theme-btn btn btn-style-three">
                          <span class="btn-title">
                            {" "}
                            Select From your device
                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </h4>
                      <input
                        name:'image'
                        style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}
                        type="file"
                        onClick={(e) => (e.target.value = null)}
                        ref={(ref) => (this.upload = ref)}
                        onChange={this.onChangeFile.bind(this)}
                        accept="image/*"`enter code here`
  />

                    </div>
```