# How can I put a ref on a cloned element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a Input component which takes an `<input>` element and renders it. It is a div, containing a label and an input.

My boss asked me that when I click anywhere in the div, it focuses on the input (so if it's a dropdown, it opens the dropdown, input, we can start writing text, etc).

I was thinking of doing it using refs: when an user clicks on the div, an onClick element is trigerred and the input gets focuses.

However, all the input are in `this.props.children`. How can I put a ref on the input and use it in my code? Here's what it looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';

export class Input extends Component {
  displayTitle () {
    if (this.props.tip) {
      return (
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name} className="lone-input-container-title">
          {this.props.title}<Tooltip placement="top" arrow title={this.props.tip}><span className="shadow-md p-1 text-hardbacon rounded-full px-2 cursor-pointer ml-2">?</span></Tooltip>
        </label>);
    }
    return (
      <label htmlFor={this.props.name} className="lone-input-container-title">
        {this.props.title}
      </label>
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="lone-input-container">
        {this.displayTitle()}
        <div>
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0])}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  tip: PropTypes.string
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar nope, my question was about putting the ref on the cloned element. Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to answer it in full. But just going to help you out. Here's my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025661/2138752) that could help you for reference.

And to use ref in cloned element, you can do like:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0], {ref: this.refElement})}
```