# cancel event on input type="file" hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I've read [Cancel event on input type="file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855400/cancel-event-on-input-type-file), but this doesn't work when input tag is hidden, the focus doesn't go to input tag.

I'm looking to re-render the button when OS file-picker closes - a. either after selecting any file, b. without selecting file and clicking on cancel button

Attaching `useState/useForceUpdate/useReducer` on `Button.onClick` or `input.onChange|onClick` event works when user actually selects file, but "not" when user clicks on cancel button without selecting file (or when user clicks on Esc key using keyboard).

`input.onFocus` doesn't get trigger. Is there a way to re-render button when user is done with file-picker closes without file selection (cancel/Esc key)?

```
const [, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

return (
    <>
        <input
            type="file"
            ref={uploadRef}
            id={`${toolbarButtonId}`}
            accept={acceptParams}
            onChange={onClickEvent}
            onClick={onClick}
            hidden
            onFocus={forceUpdate}
        />
        <Button
            ariaLabel={ariaLabel}
            ariaDescription={ariaDescription}
            disabled={disabled}
            iconName={iconName}
            id={toolbarButtonId}
            position={position}
            onClick={fileUploadRefLink}
            {...props}
        />
    </>
);
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input-using-javascript/amp/

Comment: onfocus event is not triggered when input is hidden

Comment: Please add codesandbox with minimum code which doesn't work

Comment: Would a flow like this answer suggest work? To use visible button to trigger a function which clicks the input, still giving you an onChange event on the input to work with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025558/how-to-trigger-onchange-on-input-type-file-by-another-button-click-in-reac

Answer (score 3):

You could add a focus event on the window to watch when it get focused back after the user closes the file input dialog.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let input = document.querySelector("input");

let renderCount = 0;
    
let pageRefocused =  () => {
  button.textContent = `User closed the dialog ${++renderCount} times`;
  window.removeEventListener("focus", pageRefocused);
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.click();
  // we watch the window after opening the file input dialog
  window.addEventListener("focus",pageRefocused); 
});
```

```css
input {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>Upload a file</button><input type="file">
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will `.click()` work on Safari? I remember doing something similar a while ago and Safari not really liking "fake" clicks.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test, but it did work on my iPad so 